# nodejs internals: how are arguments passed to child_process.spawn handled?

Tags: node.js

I was searching about how to escape shell arguments in nodejs when I stumbled upon this [issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/34840) on github:

> Yes, I was using execa which is a light wrapper for `childProcess.spawn` to execute a script (call it `./scripts/configure`) which took user input as an argument.
>
> One of my users supplied `"Users & Permissions Management"` as that input, which caused the script to hang as the resulting spawned process was:
>
> `./scripts/configure Users & Permissions Management`

---

*[... later ...]*

> the problem is even with `child_process.spawn` you'll still end up with incorrect command execution.
>
> `const value = "Users & Permissions Management";`
>
> `child_process.spawn('./scripts/configure', [value])`
>
> Will still result in `./scripts/configure Users & Permissions Management`, and you do sometimes need to be able to accept user input and safely pass it to another command.

Here the OP seems to claim that invoking a shell script with `child_process.spawn("./script", ["Users & Permissions Management"])` would either a) not work as intended *(whatever that means)* or b) result in untrusted code execution.

Unfortunately the issue is no longer open, so I won't be able to ask the OP directly on the issue tracker.

I'm very confused that no one questioned OP's comment as the [official](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options) nodejs documentation says:

> If the shell option is enabled, do not pass unsanitized user input to this function. Any input containing shell metacharacters may be used to trigger arbitrary command execution.

I thought that `shell` might have defaulted to `true` at some point - and therefore, explain the problem - but that doesn't seem to be the case looking (again) at the official documentation.

I also tried to replicate the problem but was unable to do so without explicitly setting `shell` to `true`.

Does anyone know what the OP of the issue meant with their comment?